# Recursively reading a file in Racket

Tags: io, scheme, racket

I am struggling to understand how to read a file line by line with racket, while passing each line to a recursive function.

According to the [manual](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/io-patterns.html), the idiomatic way of doing this is something like the following example:

```lisp
(with-input-from-file "manylines.txt"
    (lambda ()
      (for ([l (in-lines)])
         (op l))))
```

What if my function `op` is a recursive function that needs to do some complicated operations depending on the line just read from file and also on the history of the recursion?
For example, I could have a function like this:

```lisp
(define (op l s)
  ;; l is a string, s is a list
  (cond ((predicate? l)
         (op (next-line-from-file) (cons (function-yes l) s)))
        (else
         (op (next-line-from-file) (append (function-no l) s)))))
```

I am not sure how to use this function within the framework described by the manual.
Here `next-line-from-file` is a construct I made up to make it clear that I would like to keep reading the file.

I think I could do what I want by introducing side effects, for example:

```lisp
(with-input-from-file "manylines.txt"
  (lambda ()
    (let ((s '()))
      (for ([l (in-lines)])
        (if (predicate? l)
            (let ((prefix (function-yes l)))
              (set-cdr! s s)
              (set-car! s prefix))
            (let ((prefix (function-no l)))
              (set-cdr! prefix s)
              (set-car! s prefix)))))))
```

I actually did not try to run this code, so I'm not sure it would work.
Anyway I would bet that this common task can be solved without introducing side effects, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches that Racket supports rather well are to turn the port into something which is essentially a generator of lines, or into a stream.  You can then pass these things around as arguments to whatever function you are using in order to successively read lines from the file.

The underlying thing in both of these is that ports are sequences, `(in-lines p)` returns another sequence which consists of the lines from `p`, and then you can turn these into generators or streams.

Here's a function which will `cat` a file (just read its lines in other words) using a generator:

```
(define (cat/generator f)
  (call-with-input-file f
    (λ (p)
      (let-values ([(more? next) (sequence-generate (in-lines p))])
        (let loop ([carry-on? (more?)])
          (when carry-on?
            (displayln (next))
            (loop (more?))))))))
```

Here `call-with-input-file` deals with opening the file and calling its second argument with a suitable port.  `in-lines` makes a sequence of lines from the port, and `sequence-generate` then takes any sequence and returns two thunks: one tells you if the sequence is exhausted, and one returns the next thing in it if it isn't.  The remainder of the function just uses these functions to print the lines of the file.

Here's an equivalent function which does it using a stream:

```
(define (cat/stream f)
  (call-with-input-file f
    (λ (p)
      (let loop ([s (sequence->stream (in-lines p))])
        (unless (stream-empty? s)
          (displayln (stream-first s))
          (loop (stream-rest s)))))))
```

Here the trick is that `sequence->stream` returns a stream corresponding to a sequence, and then `stream-empty?` will tell you if you're at the end of the stream, and if it's not empty, then `stream-first` returns the first element (conceptually the `car`) while `stream-rest` returns a stream of all the other elements.

The second one of these is nicer I think.

---

One nice thing is that *lists are streams* so you can write functions which use the `stream-*` functions, test them on lists, and then use them on any other kind of stream, which means any other kind of sequence, and the functions will never know.

Comment: Excellent answer and excellent examples! I think these examples would be a good addition to the racket guide...

Answer (score 1):

I recently implement something similar, except in my case the predicate depended on the following line, not the preceding one. In any case, I found it simplest to discard `in-lines` and use `read-line` recursively. Since the predicate depended on unread input, I used `peek-string` to look ahead in the input stream.

If you really want to use `in-lines`, you might like to experiment with `sequence-fold`:

```
(sequence-fold your-procedure '() (in-lines))
```

Notice this uses an accumulator, which you could use to check the previous results from your procedure. However, if you're building a list, you generally want to build it backwards using `cons`, so the most recent element is at the head of the list and can be accessed in constant time. Once you're done, reverse the list.

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea of folding over a sequence (hoping that il will not generate the sequence at once, or I might run out of memory). If I understand correctly, I might just replace  `next-line-from-file` with `read-line` in my definition of `op`?

Comment: It isn't clear to me exactly what you want your code to do, but yes `read-line` does what you describe. You shouldn't run out of memory since `in-lines` creates a sequence, not a list. i.e. the data is only read as it is requested.